# получаю ошибку 405 method not allowed ASP.NET Core blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

Клиент обращается к апи. Но апи возвращает результат

> 405 method not allowed

В запросах видно что куки не проставляется

В проекте испоьльзуется HttpClient

```c
services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();
```

пробовал делать так

```c
var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials,
    AllowAutoRedirect = true
};

services.AddSingleton(sp =>
new HttpClient(handler)
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://" + domainOptions.Main)
});
```

Ошибка тогда пропадает но появляется другая, что все юзеры получаються пользуться одним httpclientom

Подскажите кто решал данную проблему!

Comment: Сумбурное описание, многое непонятно. У вас же Web Assembly? у WASM нет разницы между scoped и singleton, scoped работает как второй. Все юзеры не пользуются одним httpClient'ом - у каждого юзера своё отдельное клиентское приложение в каждой вкладке браузера. А за кулисами там вообще дёрается JS-овский httpClient. Не понятно и какие куки не проставляются, и кто их должен проставлять. Вам нужно, как-то точнее сформулировать, что у вас за проблема. И сделать так, чтобы вашу проблему было реально воспроизвести по описанию.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
Проблема следующая 
Я делаю вход под юзером и хочу получать данные через апи, по началу все работает отлично.
но через 4-5 минут я начинаю получать ошибку 405